# Why preg_match() result show 0 in PHP when I use simplexml_load_file()?

Tags: php, xml

I have some problems with php , this is my code

test.xml like:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<document responsecode="200">
  <result count="10" start="0" totalhits="133047950">
    <title>Test</title>
    <from id = "jack">655</from>
    <to>Tsung</to>
  </result>
</document>
```

php code:

```
<?php
header("content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8");
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
$text = htmlspecialchars($xml->asXML());
$pattern = "/</";
$result = preg_match($pattern,$text);
echo $result;
?>
```

The result is show "0" ,it's mean not found ,so I change $pattern value

```
$pattern = "document" ;
```

the result is show  "1" (it's mean found)

I debug a lot of time ...

Maybe codeing UTF-8 , ASCII probram OR   `"/</"`  wrong ?

My purpose is want to parse this string then get

```
'<title> .. </title>'
```

somebody can tell me where is my error ?? Thanks :))

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://eval.in/490254)

Comment: remove `$text = htmlspecialchars($xml->asXML());` Or find `&lt;`

Comment: Why are you using `htmlspecialchars`? Then it's not XML any more, because all the special characters have been encoded.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?> <document responsecode="200"> <result count="10" start="0" totalhits="133047950"> <title>Test</title> <from id="jack">655</from> <to>Tsung</to> </result> </document>

Comment: when I echo the  $text = htmlspecialchars($xml->asXML()) , I think " < "is just type of string

Comment: I know I have problems in encoded now   thx!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `htmlspecialchars`, it's converting all the XML tags to HTML entities.

```
<?php
header("content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8");
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
$text = $xml->asXML();
$pattern = "/</";
$result = preg_match($pattern,$text);
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: I used your code, if the contents of XML very a lot, It will be easy to parse something

Answer (score 2):

You are using a parser, just parse it, no need for a regex.

```
$xml = '<?xml version=\'1.0\'?>
<document responsecode="200">
  <result count="10" start="0" totalhits="133047950">
    <title>Test</title>
    <from id = "jack">655</from>
    <to>Tsung</to>
  </result>
</document>';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
echo $xml->result->title->asXML();
```

Output:

```
<title>Test</title>
```

As the other answers state the issue is your usage of `htmlspecialchars`. Your regex also isn't specific enough to find the title element. If you needed to do this with a regex you could do:

```
/((<|&lt;)title(>|&gt;).*?\2\/title\3)/
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/kM8tR8/1

Capture group 1 will have your title element. If the title text can extend multiple lines add the `s` modifier.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `htmlspecialchars()` converts special characters to HTML entities like `<` to `&lt;`, `>` to `&gt;` etc. So if you want to parse the xml document and get the `title` then you can do something like this:

```
header("content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8");
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
$text = htmlspecialchars($xml->asXML());
$pattern = "/&lt;title&gt;(.*?)&lt;\/title&gt;/";
$matches = array();
preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // Test
```

Comment: I finally know my promble is encode !!  Thank you ~